# Running guard init duplicates watcher lines

Tags: guard

I'm not sure how I've ended up here, but anytime I run `guard init`, it seems to go a bit overboard, and rather than adding coffeescript/sass/livereload once, it does each of them several times.

Here is what I get on the command line after running `guard init`:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
11:39:55 - INFO - Writing new Guardfile to /var/www/the-newbies-guide-to-test-driven-development/Guardfile
11:39:55 - INFO - coffeescript guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:55 - INFO - coffeescript guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:55 - INFO - coffeescript guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:57 - INFO - compass guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:57 - INFO - concat guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - livereload guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - livereload guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - There are 2 definitions in your Guardfile for 'livereload', you may want to clean up your Guardfile as this could cause issues.
11:39:58 - INFO - livereload guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - There are 3 definitions in your Guardfile for 'livereload', you may want to clean up your Guardfile as this could cause issues.
11:39:58 - INFO - phpunit guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - sass guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - sass guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - sass guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - sass guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - sass guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
11:39:58 - INFO - uglify guard added to Guardfile, feel free to edit it
```

With this being the contents of my `Guardfile`:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'coffeescript', :input => 'app/assets/javascripts'

guard 'coffeescript', :input => 'app/assets/javascripts'

guard 'coffeescript', :input => 'app/assets/javascripts'

guard 'compass' do
  watch('^src/(.*)\.s[ac]ss')
end

# This will concatenate the javascript files specified in :files to public/js/all.js
guard :concat, type: "js", files: %w(), input_dir: "public/js", output: "public/js/all"

guard :concat, type: "css", files: %w(), input_dir: "public/css", output: "public/css/all"

guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)$})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{public/.+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
  # Rails Assets Pipeline
  watch(%r{(app|vendor)(/assets/\w+/(.+\.(css|js|html))).*}) { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
end

guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)$})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{public/.+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
  # Rails Assets Pipeline
  watch(%r{(app|vendor)(/assets/\w+/(.+\.(css|js|html))).*}) { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
end

guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb|haml|slim)$})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{public/.+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
  # Rails Assets Pipeline
  watch(%r{(app|vendor)(/assets/\w+/(.+\.(css|js|html))).*}) { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
end

guard 'phpunit', :cli => '--colors' do
  watch(%r{^.+Test\.php$})
end

guard 'sass', :input => 'sass', :output => 'css'

guard 'sass', :input => 'sass', :output => 'css'

guard 'sass', :input => 'sass', :output => 'css'

guard 'sass', :input => 'sass', :output => 'css'

guard 'sass', :input => 'sass', :output => 'css'

guard 'uglify', :destination_file => "public/javascripts/application.js" do
  watch (%r{app/assets/javascripts/application.js})
end
```

Obviously I can just go in and remove the duplicated lines, but I was wondering why it happened in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like guard will use all available versions of a plugin when running the init - not sure if it does this when actually running too (which would be worrying). I was having the same trouble and checked my gem list:

```
gem list | grep guard
```

This showed me how many versions of guard related plugins I had installed:

```
guard (1.8.2, 1.8.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.5.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.1)
guard-concat (0.0.3)
guard-rspec (3.0.0, 2.5.3, 2.4.1, 2.3.3, 2.1.2, 1.2.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.0)
guard-sass (1.3.2)
guard-spork (0.8.0)
guard-uglify (0.1.0)
terminal-notifier-guard (1.5.3)
```

Running gem cleanup on the guard plugin that gets repeated sorted it all out:

```
gem cleanup guard-rspec

gem list | grep guard
```

Which then showed:

```
guard (1.8.2, 1.8.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.5.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.1)
guard-concat (0.0.3)
guard-rspec (3.0.0)
guard-sass (1.3.2)
guard-spork (0.8.0)
guard-uglify (0.1.0)
terminal-notifier-guard (1.5.3)
```

When I run `guard init` now I do not have repeated code in my Guardfile.

Comment: Logged a github issue on the guard project for this https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/471

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have partially solved my problem, and I've been able to remove a lot of old versions by running the `gem cleanup ...` command on them, but for some reason, I still have two versions of `guard-livereload` installed `(1.4.0, 1.0.3)` (there were three originally), and so am still getting two entries for livereload in my freshly created `Guardfile`s. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: The only reason I can think of that you have more than one version still installed is that one of your projects has a dependency on the older version. If you're using bundler it will always fulfil all dependencies. Maybe you have a gem that is locked to a particular version? The guys looking after guard have recently fixed the duplication issue though so it may be worth updating once it is released.